# Why when on android platform netstandard gets called not android

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new to Targeting multiplatforms . I have found several sources and based on them I am doing everything correctly. However once I use android device .netstandard class gets called. When iOS everything works fine.

I have tried different version of monoandroid but still the same.

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;xamarinios10;monoandroid90;</TargetFrameworks>

<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="**\*.netstandard.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="**\*.android.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="**\*.ios.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="**\*.windows.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="**\*.shared.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="**\*.shared.*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('monoandroid')) ">
    <Compile Include="**\*.android.cs" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\xml\*.xml" />
    <AndroidAsset Include="Assets\**\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: You mean that you have some problems when you target on Anadoid?

Comment: yes, the class that has .netstandard.cs is called instead

Comment: have you ever had such experience? @CherryBu-MSFT